# my excel sheet did not display result after webscrapping using selenium and export to excel

Tags: python, excel, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I would like to extract the serial number and and the expirydate from this link into excel sheet

https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-sg/product-support/servicetag/0-ZUQwbW14d28xZHZBYTZWNDdHVy80Zz090/overview

After watching tutorial on how to extract using selenium and run the code on python (using pycharm) my excel sheet was created but there is no output of the result other than the header and a chromewebsite popped out.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-sg/product-support/servicetag/0-ZUQwbW14d28xZHZBYTZWNDdHVy80Zz090/overview"
path = "C:\\Users\\ChloeChew\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"

service = Service(executable_path=path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get(url)

frame = driver.find_elements(by="xpath", value="//div[@class='product-info d-flex flex-column align-items-center d-lg-block product-info-width']")

serialnumbers = []
expirydates = []

for result in frame:
    serialnumber = driver.find_elements(by="xpath", value="//div[@class='service-tag mb-0 d-none d-lg-block']")
    expirydate = driver.find_elements(by="xpath", value="//div[@class='warrantyExpiringLabel mb-0 ml-1 mr-1']")

    serialnumbers.append(serialnumber)
    expirydates.append(expirydate)

my_dict = {'serialnumber' : serialnumbers, 'expirydate' : expirydates}
df_headlines=pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df_headlines.to_excel("practice123.xlsx")
```

I also did another code using Beautifulsoup instead but the excel sheet was completely empty (without header or anything) which is why i decided to try selenium. yet the outcome is fairly the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[I am unfamiliar with just passing a string as the first argument (`by="xpath"` rather that `By.XPATH`); if it works for you, great, but otherwise you might want to check out the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).]

The xpaths for `serialnumber` and `expirydate` might be the issue. When I inspected the page, I saw that they were inside `p` tags, not `div` tags.

On another note, if there were multiple elements in `frame`, you'd just be repeatedly getting the first serial number and expiry date, it should instead be something like

```py
# from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    serialnumber = result.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='service-tag mb-0 d-none d-lg-block']")
    expirydate = result.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='warrantyExpiringLabel mb-0 ml-1 mr-1']")
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you! Yes, i've import By , removed the For loop and continue using the same code, except i've added .text behind my serialnumber and expiry date. It worked!